# Where to define _counter for collection in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, counter

I'm having an issue in my Rails 3 app. I'm applying Ajax to a form but can't render the newly created object in my view. At the moment the problem seems to be the Rails 3 counter. When I submit the form without reloading the page, my console renders the following:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `superlative_counter' for #<#<Class:0x105bdd4a8>:0x105bd6a40>):
1: <% if superlative_counter + 1 == superlative_count && superlative_count > 1 %>
2:   <li class="superlative">
3:     and <span title="<%=h superlative.name %>"><%=h superlative.body %><p class="deleteSup"><%= link_to 'x', superlative_path(superlative), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this superlative?" %></p></span>
4:   </li>
```

Being a beginner, I'm not sure where to define the `superlative_counter` in my code. I thought the counter was just included in Rails:

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called by the collection, named after the member of the collection followed by _counter. For example, if you’re rendering @products, within the partial you can refer to product_counter to tell you how many times the partial has been rendered. This does not work in conjunction with the :as => :value option.

Here's how I render my collection:

```
<li><%= "#{@profile.first_name}" %>&nbsp;is most likely to:&nbsp;</li><%= render :partial => 'superlatives/superlative', :collection => @profile.superlatives, :locals => {:superlative_count => @profile.superlatives.length} %>
```

Here's my `_superlative.html.erb` partial:

```
<% if superlative_counter + 1 == superlative_count && superlative_count > 1 %>
  <li class="superlative">
    and <span title="<%=h superlative.name %>"><%=h superlative.body %><p class="deleteSup"><%= link_to 'x', superlative_path(superlative), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this superlative?" %></p></span>
  </li>
<% elsif superlative_count == 1 %>
  <li class="superlative">
    <span title="<%=h superlative.name %>"><%=h superlative.body %><p class="deleteSup"><%= link_to 'x', superlative_path(superlative), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this superlative?" %></p></span>
  </li>
<% else %>
<li class="superlative">
  <span title="<%=h superlative.name %>"><%=h superlative.body %><p class="deleteSup"><%= link_to 'x', superlative_path(superlative), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this superlative?" %></p></span>,&nbsp;
</li>
<% end %>
```

If anyone can help me figure out where I should define the counter I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the counter anywhere. It's initialized by Rails itself.
To me, your code looks fine.
Still, try this:
Save `@profile.superlatives` in a variable `@superlatives` and then do:

> ... :collection => @superlatives, :locals => {:superlative_count =>
>   @superlatives.length} %>

Comment: Thanks! Where should I do that?